# Trinity wallet - Keychain error on MacOS

Tags: wallet

When I am setting up a password for iota wallet I get the following error: Cannot access keychain required for secure storage.

I am on the latest version of Trinity v0.4.0 and using macOS Mojave.

Do anyone know how I can grant access to keychain?

Thanks